# Static data members being "semi-static"?

Tags: python

We have a class with static members. Some members are immutable objects and some are not:

```
class Test:
    x = 0
    y = 'ok'
    z = [1, 2, 3]

t1 = Test()
t2 = Test()
```

When printing the variables you get what you would expect:

```
print(t1.x, t2.x)
print(t1.y, t2.y)
print(t1.z, t2.z)
```

```
0 0
ok ok
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2, 3]
```

And I can modify the value of the immutable static members:

```
Test.x = 1
print(t1.x, t2.x)
```

```
1 1
```

But I can also modify these values separately for each instance:

```
t1.x = 5
t2.x = 7
print(t1.x, t2.x)
```

```
5 7
```

Same happens to strings:

```
Test.y = 'okk'
print(t1.y, t2.y)

t1.y = 'foo'
t2.y = 'bar'
print(t1.y, t2.y)
```

```
okk okk
foo bar
```

But with the immutable members things are different:

```
Test.z += [4]
print(t1.z, t2.z)

t1.z += [5]
t2.z += [6]
print(t1.z, t2.z)
```

```
[1, 2, 3, 4] [1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The instance-based member access also affects the other instances of the class.

I would like to know more about how these "static" members behave in the background. Using my own knowledge I was able to think of the following:

1. *I know* ints are immutable, so while both `t1` and `t2` may point to the same `0` or `1` instance, *I guess* when we assign them different values, they start pointing to different memory locations.
2. *I guess* Point 1. is possible because Python lacks a proper implementation for a lot of features, classes and namespaces are basically the same thing, we do not have a completely implicit `self`/`this` and we still have to specify it, no proper `private`/`protected` access, no proper `const`-ness. So it is not hard for me to believe (but I would like confirmation or more info on this) that Python also does not have a proper implementation of the concept of "static" class members. One possibility I can think of is that all "static" member are actually instance members and `Test.x` is just a syntactic sugar for iterating and reassigning ALL instances of `Test.x`.
3. Point 2. would explain this behaviour, and why the immutable object access, even through instances, affects all instances, because `Test.z` is not being reassigned, only accessed, and then methods of that object are called (such as `__iadd__`).

Is this correct? Or what exactly is the mechanism for the "static but not really" class members?

Comment: `t1.x = 5` is _shadowing_ the class attribute `Test.x` with an instance attribute of the same name. `Test.z += [4]`/`t1.z += [5]` is acting on the _list_, not `Test` or `t1` (the equivalent to the integer behaviour would be `t1.z = t1.z + [5]`).